# Random numbers and while loop issues

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I have to generate two random numbers for 52000 instances in an ArrayList, attack 1 and attack 2, where attack 1 must be greater than attack 2, so i have to put them in the list. This is my sample code:

```
do {
    atk_p1 = (int) (Math.random() * (5000-500+1)+500);
    atk_p2 = (int) (Math.random() * (5000-500+1)+500);
} while(atk_p1 <= atk_p2);

data.add(String.valueOf(atk_p1));
data.add(String.valueOf(atk_p2));
```

My problem is that the above code sometimes works (thus `atk_p1` is greater than `atk_p2`) but other times not (thus `atk_p2` is greater than `atk_p1`). I'm trying to solve the issue. Thank you for your help.

The above code is Java.

Comment: What programming language is this? Please update the question with that info and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Why not generate the second number with the first number as the upper limit thus negating the need for the do...while loop?

Comment: In the text you keep saying "greater than", but in the code you write "greater than or equal". Which one do you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to generate `a` and `b` and then do simple comparison check to see if `b` is smaller than `a`.

If it is not you simply swap `a` and `b`.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't come up on my 'phone. Include the bit about when equal (doesn't have to have the lottery stuff) and I'll delete mine. I can't see a simpler solution, and language-independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate two random numbers, `a` and `b`, such that `a < b`, then

1. Generate `a`.
2. Generate `b` as `a` plus a random number greater than zero.

EDIT: This is wrong, and I admit it. See comments below. Mea culpa.

Comment: What if that breaks the upper limit for  valid b?

Comment: @BillWoodger You know `a`, you know your upper limit `m`, then `b = a + 1 (r % (m - a - 1))`, where `r` is a random number.  The `+1` and `-1` are necessary for strict inequality.  I still don't know what language this is so I have no clue about what that `random()` thingy returns.

Comment: Assuming there is some limit to the upper boundary of the random number generated, then a + some new random number can break that. I don't know whether your algebra is proving or disproving that, but it is so. See SilverWarrior's answer.

Comment: At the moment, the OP is not restricting the upper limit of the generated numbers, as far as I can see. Also, I *still* don't know if `random()` returns an integer value (which I have assumed) or a float value (in which case tho math is different) because I don't know this language.

Comment: So you're expecting that there is some language out there, which has a random function (perhaps specific) which has no limit, and that that is the one that the questioner is using? Medium-random-number + high-random-number = busted-random-number in all cases (all languages) which do not provide a limit on a specific random-number function for some esoteric purpose. What am I missing?

Comment: No. I'm expecting the programmer to make sure that the generated numbers are within the right ranges.  When, in my answer, I said "a random number" I don't mean a pure `random()` call. I mean "generate a random number that make sense in this context".

Comment: Also, in the more general case of having *a number* `a` and wanting to generate a random number `b` such that `a < b`, you can't really just swap the values of `a` and `b` to make it work. You need to take `a` into consideration when generating `b`.

Comment: I do not like this approach.  The second number is not selected from the full available range, but only from a part of the range.  That makes it 'less random' in some sense then the first number.  Better to pick both numbers from the full range and, if necessary, switch them into the right order as @SilverWarrior suggests.

Comment: @rossum The two numbers have a dependency, therefore they are not "as random as they could be". If you switch them, you have imposed limits on them. Afterwards, you have `a` and can say something about the value of `b` (that it is greater).

Comment: The swapping is done *after* picking the second number.  Each number is picked from the full range of possibilities.  By pre-limiting the allowed range for the second pick it is not going to be a statistical match for the first pick.

Comment: @rossum I now see that you are correct, but I had to come up with a thought experiment involving picking more than two numbers, and what would happen if the first number was towards the end of the range.

Answer (score 0):

I would just generate the second random number with the first one as it's upper limit:

```
atk_p1 = (int) (Math.random() * (5000-500+1)+501);
atk_p2 = (int) (Math.random() * (atk_p1)+500);

data.add(String.valueOf(atk_p1));
data.add(String.valueOf(atk_p2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
   int atk_p1 = 0;
   int atk_p2 = 0;

   data.add(String.valueOf(atk_p1));
   data.add(String.valueOf(atk_p2));

   do{
    atk_p1 = (int) (Math.random() * (5000-500+1)+500);
    atk_p2 = (int) (Math.random() * (5000-500+1)+500);
   }while(atk_p1 == atk_p2);


  if(atk_p1 > atk_p2){
    data.set(34, String.valueOf(atk_p1));
    data.set(36, String.valueOf(atk_p2));
  }else{
    data.set(34, String.valueOf(atk_p2));
    data.set(36, String.valueOf(atk_p1));
  }
```

The problem was the arraylist.add() operation, it is not strict to the sequential order of the instructions. Using indexes to specify where to put the information worked great.